# MySQL Update current record in table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've been trying to come up with an elegant way to do the following, let's say I have the following table:

```
+-----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------+
| ID  | EmpNum  |    Name    |    Title     | StartDate  | UpdateDate | IsCurr |
+-----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------+
|   1 | 0000001 | John Smith | Engineer     | 01/01/2017 | 01/02/2017 | N      |
|   2 | 0000001 | John Smith | Sr. Engineer | 01/01/2017 | NULL       | Y      |
+-----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

When the Title of the employee changes, I want to update the `UpdateDate` of the current employee record and change `IsCurr` to `N`, then insert the new record which will be the current one. For example if employee `John Smith` got promoted to Team Lead on 01/03/2017, then the resulting table would like this.

+-----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+----

```
----+
| ID  | EmpNum  |    Name    |    Title     | StartDate  | UpdateDate | IsCurr |
+-----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------+
|   1 | 0000001 | John Smith | Engineer     | 01/01/2017 | 01/02/2017 | N      |
|   2 | 0000001 | John Smith | Sr. Engineer | 01/01/2017 | 01/03/2017 | N      |
|   3 | 0000001 | John Smith | Team Lead    | 01/01/2017 | NULL       | Y      |
+-----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

From what I can tell MySQL does not have a `MERGE` function so I would need to this in 2 separate commands. As in `UPDATE` the most recent record and then insert the new row.
Is there a better way to do this in MySQL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to arrange your desired query with [INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). But you need ID to be an index.
It is available since MySQL version 5.5.

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, EmpNum, Name, Title, StartDate, UpdateDate, IsCurr) 
VALUES
(3, '0000001', 'John Smith', 'Team Lead', '01/01/2017', NULL, 'Y'),
(2, '0000001', 'John Smith', 'Sr. Engineer', '01/01/2017', '01/03/2017', 'N')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE isCurr='N', UpdateDate='01/03/2017';
```

Comment: I did consider `ON DUPLICATE KEY` but I am inserting a completely new record into that table, so I need to verify the existence of previous records of the same employee via some other fields.

Comment: Not sure if overthinking, but if you use a subquery to SELECT the most recent record and use it inside of the VALUES of INSERT INTO might work.